# Does mongoose ordered Model.insertMany write anything to the db if it fails?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In the documentation for Model.insertMany, it says that when options.ordered == true the method will fail on the 1st error.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.insertMany

> [options.ordered «Boolean» = true] if true, will fail fast on the
>   first error encountered. If false, will insert all the documents it
>   can and report errors later. An insertMany() with ordered = false is
>   called an "unordered" insertMany().

Does it:

- have an error and write no documents to the db. (what I would like)

or

- write documents that occur before the error, have an error, then not write any more documents?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**options.ordered = true (the default):**

> Mongoose always validates each document before sending **insertMany** to
>   MongoDB. So if one document has a validation error, no documents will
>   be saved, unless you set the **ordered option to false**.

***Note this is validation not how it handles exceptions during insert.***

If all documents pass validation then from [MongoDb docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/#error-handling):

> Excluding Write Concern errors, ordered operations **stop after an
>   error**, while unordered operations **continue to process** any remaining
>   write operations in the queue.

Note the last paragraph under the examples for `insertMany`:

> Note that one document **was inserted**: The first document of _id: 13
>   will insert successfully, but the second insert will fail. **This will
>   also stop additional documents left in the queue from being inserted**.
>
> **With ordered to false, the insert operation would continue with any
>   remaining documents.**

You seem to imply that you need a [transactional approach](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/#transactions). For which you should look [into this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/) and see if your MongoDB version supports it.

**options.ordered = false:**

Since you the explicitly specified that you do not care about the insert order it would keep inserting and simply **skip** the ones with exceptions.

Also from [MongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/):

> If ordered is set to false, documents are inserted in an unordered
>   format and may be reordered by mongod to increase performance.
>   Applications should not depend on ordering of inserts if using an
>   unordered insertMany().